# How do I solve $\int\limits_C (x+y)\;\mathrm{d}x+(x-y)\;\mathrm{d}y$?

Tags: calculus, line-integrals

I just need someone to confirm that I am right or fix me. Maybe someone will show better ways.

Here's the line integral (second type):

$$\int\limits_C (x+y)\;\mathrm{d}x+(x-y)\;\mathrm{d}y$$

where $C$ is given by ellipse $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$

Theory says that we have to get rid either of all $x$ or all $y$. But it is well known that function that defines ellipse is implicit, so there is no way to express either $x$ or $y$. So I took standard parametrization:

$$\begin{cases}x = a\cos t \\ y = b\sin t \\ 0 \le t \le 2\pi\end{cases}$$

and also the following differentials:

$$\begin{cases} \mathrm{d}x = -a\sin t\,\mathrm{d}t \\ \mathrm{d}y = b\cos t\,\mathrm{d}t \end{cases}$$

After all that it is possible to write down usual definite integral, like:

$$\int_0^{2\pi}(a\cos t+b\sin t)(-a\cos t)+(a\cos t-b\sin t)(b\cos t)\;\mathrm{d}t\ldots$$

The rest should be just easy (get rid of brackets, use linear rule of integration, fracting constants out and so on).

Am I right?

P.S. Also have doubts about $0\le x \le 2\pi$ limits for defenite integral...

Comment: Yes, that's a correct way to solve. One tiny (syntactic) addition: $\mathrm dx=-a\sin t\,\mathrm dt$.

Comment: You are right and the limits are right. You need to go all the way around the ellipse. You're right that it's easy from here provided you know how to do $\int \cos^2(t)dt$, etc.

Comment: Do you know Green's Theorem? If so, that might be an easier way to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the partial of x+y with respect to y =1 = the partial of x-y with respect to x .Therefore the form of the line integral is exact so the integral around the closed curve is 0 .

Comment: Is it a joke ? You answered 10 questions but you don't know how to use latex ?